# поддомены nginx не перенаправляет

Tags: linux, nginx

Есть конфиг для главного сайта и поддомена
проблема в том что по обоим адресам открываеться скрипт по адресу root /var/www/example/html/bin;
по второму адресу открываеться скрипт только если ввести в ссылке порт на котором он работает (zt.example.com:4000)
где я ошибся???

```
# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com:
server {
listen 80 ;
listen [::]:80 ;
server_name example.com www.example.com;
root /var/www/example/html/bin;
index www;
location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;

    }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/zt.example.com:
server {
listen 80 ;
listen [::]:80 ;
server_name zt.example.com www.zt.example.com;
root /var/www/zt.example.com/html/bin;
index ztwww;
location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;

    }
}
```

Comment: Nginx перезапустили? Что говорит `nginx -t`?

Comment: И проверьте имена доменов на предмет опечаток

Comment: @Alexey Ten
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful                                                           все перепроверял, уже третьи сутки не могу понять почему не работает.

Comment: Тогда проверяйте опечатки. Приведённый код должен работать

Comment: `обоим адресам открываеться скрипт по адресу root` по конфигам это не так

Comment: 99% типичных проблем решается: 1) `nginx -t && nginx -s reload` 2) Очистка кэша браузера или использование режима инкогнито. Это делалось?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. С настройками было всё нормально, я каким то чудным образом настроил сервер так, что он в обход nginx прослушивал порт 3000.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).